# React Apex Charts - Reversed yAxis issue

Tags: reactjs, graph, charts, apex

I work on a graphs project and use Apex Charts.

As I use days on y axis, I would like to have days from Monday on top to Sunday at the bottom.

The issue is when I use y axis "reversed: true" it compact the graph...
Don't know why and I have no clue about it...

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help.

What I have normally.
[image: what I have normally]

What I have with reversed on true (it's all the graph here).
[image: what I have with the reversed on true]

The only difference in my code.

[image]

[image]